# Change SVG image code based on iPad orientation with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ipad, svg, orientation

I need a way to change an image width and height, inside an SVG, based on the orientation of the device, using Javascript (or ECMAScript, inside the SVG).

I'm using this code, but it's not affecting the image element inside the SVG.

```
// SVG code, inside XHTML file
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="birds" height="569px" id="bird01" version="1.1" width="368px" x="0px" xml:space="preserve" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" y="0px">
  <g>
    <defs>
      <rect class="crop" height="569" id="SVGID_1_" width="368"></rect>
    </defs>
    <use overflow="visible" xlink:href="#SVGID_1_"></use>
    <g clip-path="url(#SVGID_2_)">
      <image clip-path="url(#SVGID_2_)" height="846" id="bird-img" overflow="visible" width="547" xlink:href="../Images/bird.jpeg"></image>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>

// JS code, outside file, referenced in head

window.onload = function initialLoad() {
     detectOrientation();
}

detectOrientation();
    window.onorientationchange = detectOrientation;
    function detectOrientation(){
        if(typeof window.onorientationchange != 'undefined'){
            if ( orientation == 0 ) {
                 document.getElementById("bird-img").setAttribute("width", "547").setAttribute("height", "846");
            }
            else if ( orientation == 90 ) {
                 document.getElementById("bird-img").setAttribute("width", "368").setAttribute("height", "568");
            }
            else if ( orientation == -90 ) {
                 document.getElementById("bird-img").setAttribute("width", "368").setAttribute("height", "568");
            }
            else if ( orientation == 180 ) {
                 document.getElementById("bird-img").setAttribute("width", "547").setAttribute("height", "846");
            }
        }
    }
```

This link show a test page: http://bit.ly/mSBDhq Adjust the window size to see the SVG box changing it's size. I just want the image size adjusted to the width of SVG box in both cases (landscape and portrait). I'm using CSS media queries to do most of the work, but the SVG image element isn't affected by the CSS, that's the reason I'm looking for an JS solution. I appreciate any lights on this.

Side note: unfortunately, in this case, I simply can not use a regular image tag and CSS property overflow combined with media queries to achieve this effect (long story).

Comment: Does declaring the function before calling it help?

Comment: Can you clarify what does happen? Is `detectOrientation` getting called? Are you getting into the correct if statement branch? (BTW, you might want to use a `switch` here for brevity.) Is `getElementById` returning the correct object? After you set the attributes are they changed (in the DOM) but you're seeing no effect on screen?

Comment: Phrogz's answer help to clear some issues, but even after this the element is not affected... maybe js can't reach inside svg.

Answer (score 0):

Note that [`setAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) does not return the receiver. Indeed, it [has no return value](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-F68F082), per the spec. This is not jQuery.

Let's DRY up your function a little and fix it at the same time:

```js
function detectOrientation(){
  if(typeof window.onorientationchange == 'undefined') return;
  var img = document.getElementById('bird-img');
  switch(orientation){
    case 0:
    case 180:
      img.setAttribute('width',547);
      img.setAttribute('height',846);
    break;
    case 90:
    case -90:
      img.setAttribute('width',368);
      img.setAttribute('height',568);
    break;
  }
}
```

**Edit**: Proof that when the code is run it affects the image (in Chrome at least):

[image]
<sub>(source: [phrogz.net](http://phrogz.net/tmp/ResizedBird.png))</sub>

Comment: Thanks, Phrogz, you suggestions solved the issues with the original JS. But the "image" element inside de SVG it's not affected yet, look:  http://bit.ly/mSBDhq. If I use a regular img tag, outside the SVG code, everything works great. But no luck with the image element. Probably because SVG has its own namespace, but I don't know how to integrate the JS code with it...

Comment: @pagelab I don't have an iPad to test this, but in Chrome your JS function is not getting called. See the edit to my question for proof that it should work if the JS is called.

Comment: True. I have tried several calling methods with no luck. Can't see why the function it's not working.

Comment: @pagelab Perhaps you need to create a new question with just that topic: how to detect orientation changes in JS.